# Modus Ponens Proof

Tags: logic

I have written the truth table for all of the forms of $P$ and $Q$.
Then maintained the table to find $P \rightarrow Q $ and $[(P \rightarrow Q) \wedge P]$.As we know, we can write arguments in forms of $[Expression_{one} \wedge Expression_{two}]\rightarrow Result $ 
Right now, I have the table with all possible forms of $P$ and $Q$ which leads to their conclusions.How can I prove that *Modus Ponens* is a valid argument according to the table I have written?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which definition of "valid argument" are you using?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Valid means if you consider the premises to be true, then the conclusion must be true.However, I don't know any other definition of a valid argument and I appreciate if you could possibly explain all possible cases.

Comment: Why nobody answers my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a truth table for $(P \to Q) \wedge P$ note that whenever the whole statement is true, $Q$ is also true.

Comment: Did you mean, whenever the whole statement is true $P$ is true?

Comment: @FreeMind Modus Ponens states that if we have $(P \to Q) \land P$, then we can get $Q$. A rule is valid if the truth of its conclusion follows from the truth of its premises. So you have to show that if the premise $(P \to Q) \land P$ is true, you can get the truth of the conclusion $Q$.

Answer (score 4):

*Modus ponens* rule is :

> from $P \rightarrow Q$ and $P$, infer $Q$.

This rule correspond to the *soundness* of the "argument" :

> $P \rightarrow Q, P \vDash Q$

where an argument is *sound* when, from true *premises*, licences the derivation of a true *conclusion*.

This means that *modus ponens* is equivalent to :

> $\vDash ((P \rightarrow Q) \land P) \rightarrow Q$,

i.e. $((P \rightarrow Q) \land P) \rightarrow Q$ is a *tautology*.

Thus, as said in the above answer, you can check it with a truth table.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple: Basically, if Modes Ponens is a valid inference rule, then whenever we know some P implies Q, and at the same time we know that P happened to be true, then Q must be true. So, basically,

the Modes Ponens is this statement: (((P => Q) & P) => Q)

And that statement should, at the end (i.e., in the last column of the last Q, be TRUE for all truth values of P and Q, and it will). Do the truth table for the above statement

There's another branches of mathematics that also verify the validity of Modes Ponens (e.g, probability theory and set theory). if you like I can supply the simple proof there too.