# Modus ponens as a rule of inference vs. tautology

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, axioms

When I look up the mechanics of a propositional logic system [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Generic_description_of_a_propositional_calculus) we have a collection of both rules of inference ($a \vdash b$) and axioms ($\vdash b$), if I understand right.

One such rule of inference is modus ponens, $p, (p\to q) \vdash q$ which on a metalogical level is "from $p$ and $p\to q$, infer $q$".

However I have also seen people "prove" it using truth tables or treating it as a tautology by stating it as $(p \land (p\to q)) \to q$.

Why do I see it stated these two ways if the latter is not technically modus ponens? Is it totally and utterly wrong to even ask the question how to "prove modus ponens" because it's considered a rule of inference, i.e. it has no proof since it's a metalogical assumption? Why do I sometimes see it stated the second way, if so, and how do we know that's the correct interpretation as a tautological claim?

I know informally it makes sense as "if $a$ then $b$" or "whenever $a$ is true, $b$ is true" but the whole $\vdash$ concept seems to be a little different from $\to$ (especially since $\vdash$ is metalogical) and so I'm trying to understand what's going on here.

Comment: *NB:* $p \land (p\to q) \to q$ is missing parentheses.

Comment: Very relevant here: [What the tortoise said to Achilles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351685/whats-the-problem-this-logic)

Comment: In particular Peter Smith's _answer_ to the linked question is a good and complete answer to this one, too.

Comment: @HenningMakholm reading that question and answer I'm still not sure I understand the problem. Sounds like he's just saying "just because you say it implies Z, I'm not convinced" until you make a specific rule that overrides that need to be convinced. Which to me is not directly addressing the difference between usage of implies and infers with respect to modus ponens

Comment: To prove $(p \land (p\to q)) \to q$. using truth tables, you have to use the truth table for material implication, which is usually presented simply as a definition. Each line of that truth table, however, can also be derived using well-known principles of logic including MP, direct proof (introducing $\to$), proof by contradiction and double negation.

Comment: Modus ponens is usually the name of the *rule of inference* : "from $P$ and $P \to Q$, derive $Q$". But we may call *MP* also the tautology : $((P \land (P \to Q)) \to Q)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I stated in [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2894658/305738), the *rule* modus ponens is part of the *definition* of many common proof systems. Let **HPC** stand for Hilbert's system for classical propositional logic whose *only* rule of inference is modus ponens and whose axioms are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems#Implication_and_negation) after Frege's. This is a well-defined mathematical object. It is one proof system for classical propositional logic. Literally over a dozen others are mentioned on that page, and those are restricted to Hilbert-style proof systems. There are also many others in the style of natural deduction or the sequent calculus.

In **HPC** a (formal) proof is either an instance of one of the axioms, or it is a use of the rule modus ponens which combines two other proofs. This produces a binary-tree-like structure whose leaves are instances of axioms. This is the definition of a proof in **HPC**. A formula of classical propositional logic is **proven** by **HPC** if we can build a proof which has that formula as the conclusion (i.e. the root of the tree). This is an example of the syntactic approach to logic. We don't even need to *formulate* the idea of "truth tables" to completely specify this.

An alternate approach is semantics. Here there are no axioms or rules. Instead, we need to provide a way of interpreting formulas as some mathematical object (in a compositional way, but I won't elaborate on that). There are many possible semantics you could use. *One* possibility is to use a [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)), and, in particular, the simplest possible non-trivial Boolean algebra built on a two element set. *Any* two element set will do. Let's use $\{\mathsf{cat},\mathsf{dog}\}$ for concreteness. With this *choice* of semantics, formulas with $n$ (distinct) propositional variables become $n$-ary operations on that two element set. Now we *define* a formula to be "**true**" if its *interpretation* is function that constantly has the value $\mathsf{dog}$. Dually from before, we can completely specify this semantics without ever mentioning *any* notion of formal proof.

Now we can ask the question: are the formulas that **HPC** proves the same as the formulas that the Boolean algebra semantics calls "true"? The soundness theorem for **HPC** with respect to this Boolean algebra semantics states that the formulas that **HPC** proves are "true" in the semantics. The completeness theorem for **HPC** with respect to this Boolean algebra semantics states that every formula that is "true" in the semantics has a proof in **HPC**. These (meta-)theorems can be proven either with informal mathematical reasoning or formally within some richer logical framework.

At no point in this do you need to accept the rules or axioms of **HPC** or agree that the Boolean algebra semantics I gave correctly reflects some philosophical notion of truth. This is no different from studying any other mathematical object. If I'm studying the ring of square matrices, I don't have to reject my prior notions of addition and multiplication and accept matrix addition/multiplication as the One True Meaning of addition and multiplication. I don't need to have a first principles account of how there is no other way of adding and multiplying matrices. (There *are* other ways of adding and multiplying matrices!) The formulas proven by **HPC** are the same regardless of one's philosophical stance. The formulas that are "true" with respect to the Boolean algebra semantics are the same regardless of one's philosophical stance. One's philosophical stance simply doesn't come into it.<sup>1</sup>

The only time I would need to convince you of the axioms/rules of **HPC** is if I'm making a philosophical claim that they correspond to some philosophical notion of "truth". There are plenty of reasons to study classical propositional logic quite apart from philosophical notions of "truth" such as applications to digital circuits. Similarly, there are plenty of reasons to study intuitionistic logics unrelated to philosophical notions of truth such as extracting computational content from constructive proofs or proving theorems that hold for a much broader and mathematically important class of semantics than classical logics. There are good reasons to study both simultaneously, and there is no cognitive dissonance in doing so.

As to some people calling $(p\land(p\to q))\to q$ "modus ponens", it wouldn't be the first time in mathematics that two distinct but related concepts were given the same name. That said, I think many of the times you see that it is being said by someone who doesn't have (or at least hasn't demonstrated that they have) a clear understanding of the separation between logic and meta-logic. Like your earlier question, if you try to naively formalize the usual informal description of the rule modus ponens but don't take care to separate syntax from semantics and logic from meta-logic, then you readily get the above formula. If you do take care to keep these separate, it is readily apparent that treating the above formula as the formalization of the rule modus ponens is a mish-mash of logic and meta-logic.

Write $\vdash p$ for the *meta-logical* claim that **HPC** proves $p$. The typical informal description of the rule modus ponens is: "if $p$ is provable and $p\to q$ is provable, then $q$ is provable". Let me write that a bit more formally. To make the distinction between logic and meta-logic a bit clearer, I'll write $\curlywedge$ and $\leadsto$ for the meta-logical conjunction and implication. The informal "modus ponens" is then more formally: $((\vdash p)\curlywedge(\vdash(p\to q)))\leadsto(\vdash q)$. This has the form $(\varphi\curlywedge\psi)\leadsto \chi$ where $\varphi$, $\psi$, and $\chi$ are atomic propositions in the meta-logic. Saying $(p\land(p\to q))\to q$ is a tautology is *via the soundness and completeness theorems* equivalent to saying $\vdash ((p\land(p\to q))\to q)$. This is an atomic proposition of the meta-logic. It should be clear now why I speak of a mish-mash. Viewing these two meta-logical propositions as being the same leads to $\to$ being used for both the $\to$ connective of the logic and the meta-logical $\leadsto$.

Still, if someone wants to *call* $(p\land(p\to q))\to q$ "modus ponens", that's their prerogative. It's no different than saying you are going to call it $A$. If, however, they are claiming it is the formalization of the rule modus ponens, then they are simply wrong.

<sup>1</sup> This isn't completely true as one's philosophical stance on truth impacts their informal reasoning. For example, an ultrafinitist might reject the claim that sufficiently large formulas of classical propositional logic *can* have proofs in **HPC** or *can* be shown to be "true" in the Boolean algebra semantics. However, a classical mathematician, an ultrafinitist, and an intuitionist will all agree that $p\lor\neg p$ is provable in **HPC** and is "true" with respect to the Boolean algebra semantics. They just may not agree that **HPC** is a good reflection of their (philosophical) notion of "truth".

Comment: @DerekElkins When you say "We can use modus ponens to build a proof of $Q$"... is the proof of $Q$ not "built" for us once we have proven $P$ as well as $P \to Q$? Is showing that both $P$ true and $P \to Q$ true the very definition of what it means to build the proof of $Q$ under modus ponens?

Comment: @user525966 No.  If you have a proof of P, and one of (P->Q), you have to write another line where Q is.  The proof analysis will refer to P, and (P->Q) provided that such exists.

Comment: @user525966 A formal proof is a mathematical object. I described it for **HPC** as a binary tree (subject to some constraints I didn't state). A proof of $P$ is one of these binary trees with root labelled $P$. A proof of $P\to Q$ is a binary tree with root labelled $P\to Q$. A pair of trees is not a binary tree, but we can make a binary tree from them, in particular, a tree with root labelled $Q$ with those two trees as children. This would satisfy the constraints, thus we could call this new binary tree a proof of $Q$. There is no showing of anything as being "true" involved in any of this.

Comment: @DerekElkins I understand the "binary tree" concept but I'll rephrase my question maybe: If we have a proof of $P$, and a proof that $P \to Q$, do we now have a proof of $Q$?

Comment: @user525966 No. A pair of trees is not a tree. Or, if I write my proof as a numbered list of steps, I still have to write "$Q$ from steps 53 and 728 via MP". I can't assume the reader will figure out that they should use modus ponens with steps 53 and 728. Taken to the extreme, if I had a proof of $Q$ merely by having a proof of $P$ and $P\to Q$, then I'd have a proof of any provable formula merely by listing (instances of) the axioms. Checking a proof should be a mechanical process that we know will terminate. There is no guarantee of termination for *finding* a proof (for logics in general).

Comment: @DerekElkins But if that's the case, it now seems like a situation of $p \land (p \to q) \to q$ rather than $p, p \to q \vdash q$, since normally the $\to$ in a mathematical proof means "is possible to arrive at, given that we continue to use valid operations", $\to$ taking us from one statement to another

Comment: @user525966 That's not true at all. Having $p\to q$ doesn't imply that $q$ is derivable in any way. Like proofs, formulas are mathematical objects. In fact, they are also (textual representations of) tree-like structures called syntax trees. They don't have any inherent meaning. What I said about proofs applies to formulas too. $p\to q$ is no more a declarative statement than $2+3$. Instead "$p$ is provable" or "$p$ is valid" are declarative statements. Admittedly, such meta-logical predicates like "is provable" are often left implied which is another vector for logic/meta-logic conflations.

Comment: I am confused then because earlier you said probability is a metalogical claim, yes? But then what's wrong with "$p$ is provable" as a declarative statement, which is some kind of meaning we attach to $p$?

Comment: @user525966 Nothing is wrong with "$p$ is provable" being a declarative statement. That's what I explicitly said it was in the previous comment. In particular, it is a declarative statement of the (in this case informal) meta-logic. $2+3$ isn't a declarative statement, but "$2+3$ is even" is. My previous comment is exactly in-line with David C. Ullrich's answer to your new question. I also said formulas don't have *inherent* meaning. A proof system or a semantics can indirectly give them meaning, but we can give multiple, incompatible proof systems/semantics for the same language of formulas.

Comment: So all of this we're talking about right now, is this still in the realm of propositional logic, or formal logic, or are there multiple flavors of metalogic, etc? Like what's the most fundamental level of all this stuff? How far down does this go?

Comment: "Meta-logic" is just the term for the logical framework that is being used to study the formal object language. You can use any logical framework you want for the meta-logic. As far as you're concerned the "most fundamental level" is your own informal reasoning abilities. Not only would you need to use your own reasoning to decide to adopt some other purported "fundamental" system, you would need to use your own reasoning to even understand a description of it. You are using your informal reasoning abilities right now to parse and understand this sentence.

Comment: @DerekElkins It's just a little confusing since in the other answer comment chain with David he mentions that even the $\vdash$ symbol is being used in two different ways depending on context, which to me implies multiple levels of metalogic

Answer (score 1):

"Why do I see it stated these two ways if the latter is not technically modus ponens?"

Because people don't think about this much or are confused.

" Is it totally and utterly wrong to even ask the question how to "prove modus ponens" because it's considered a rule of inference, i.e. it has no proof since it's a metalogical assumption?"

Given that "proof" means "formal proof" where a formal proof has every step being a well-formed formula, then yes.  Why?  Because {(p->q), p} $\vdash$ q (I note in passing that {p, q} and {q, p} are the same set, so I referred to the same rule of inference as you did) is not a well-formed formula in the same context where "formal proof" applies to for propositional calculus.

"Why do I sometimes see it stated the second way, if so, and how do we know that's the correct interpretation as a tautological claim?"

At the very least, the well-formed formula (one you would parenthesize it) is just one well-formed formula.  The antecedent is a single well-formed *conjunction* also, and sometimes *conjunction* is not a primitive, and sometimes not even a defined connective, for a propositional calculus.  On the other hand, {(p->q), p} consists of a set of two well-formed formulas.

$\vdash$ is not a connective between propositions.  If we where to write:

"If p, if (p->q) also, then q" we would have stepped outside of propositional calculus, since "if", "then", "also, and "," are not part of the language for well-formed formulas in propositional calculus.  In other words, they are not part of the "formula language".

However, "$\vdash$" doesn't happen inside of the formula language.  If we wrote:

"If p, if (p>q) also, $\vdash$ q"

we haven't stepped outside of the meta-language where $\vdash$ comes as permissible, since there doesn't exist any formation rules prescribing the correct or incorrect use of $\vdash$ other than it gets used intelligibly.  So, as long as the above comes as comprehensible to the reader, it qualifies as correct.  That differs from the use of (well-formed) formulas, where every string used needs to follow the formation rules to stay in the language.