# Difference between $\to$, $\models$ and $\implies$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have a problem understanding the difference between $\to$, $\implies$ and $\models$.

The way I understand it is as follows:

$\to$ is used inside a formula between propositions. So saying $ A \to B $ is a formula.

$ \models $ is a statement about formulas. So saying $ A \land B \models A \lor B $ is making a statement about those two formulas $ A \land B $ and $ A \lor B $  and their relationship to each other.

And now comes my confusion: 
Where does $\implies$ come in all this?

My textbook made the following distinction:

"$ F \equiv \top $ is statement about formulas, so we can write (1) $F \equiv \top \implies G \equiv \top $. But this is not the same as (2) $F \models G$. "

But why not? Is it because $\models $ and $ \equiv$ are on the same level? And if yes, then on what level is $\implies$? Is it a statement about a statement about formulas?

Thank you

Comment: $I \vDash A$ is a statement about an [interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic)) $I$ of a formal language and a formula $A$ in that language. More precisely, $I \vDash A$ means that the $A$ is true in $I$, i.e., every [valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic)) in $I$ satisfies $A$.

Comment: See the post [$\to$ vs. $\vdash$ in logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903877/to-vs-vdash-in-logic)

Comment: And see the post [Meaning of symbols $\vdash$ and $\vDash$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115066/meaning-of-symbols-vdash-and-models) and linked posts.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I read both posts and a few more before posting my question but $ \vdash $ only added to my confusion. Can you explain that specific distinction my textbook made?

Comment: The meaning of $\Rightarrow$ is "implies" or "imply". In general, this is used to relate a hypothesis statement that implies in a thesis statement ("if..., then...").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your book uses $\to$ as a [logical connective (the *conditional*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#List_of_common_logical_connectives), i.e. as a "syntactical object" of the Language of propositional calculus (see page 15).

The symbol : $\top$ denotes the logical constant $\text {TRUE}$ and $\bot$ denotes the $\text {FALSE}$; they are not part of the language (in other cases, they are, and thus $F \to \bot$ is a *formula*, that can be used as definition for $\lnot F$).

The symbol $\equiv$ is used by your book **not** as the bi-conditional connective ($\leftrightarrow$, see page 16) but as a meta-mathematical abbreviation for the rleation of (logical) *equivalence* (see page 17).

Thus

> $F \equiv \top$

is **not** a formula of the language but reads "the formula $F$ is equivalent to the True", i.e. "$F$ is always true", i.e. $F$ is a *tautology* (see page 20), and thus it is a statement about the formula $F$.

As explicitly stated in the book (page 19), the symbol is a synonym of the usual way to denote the fact that a formula $F$ is a tautology : $\vDash F$.

The book uses $\Leftrightarrow$ as an abreviation for "iff" : this symbol is not part of the language but is part of the meta-language, i.e. it is not used to write formulas but to express relations between formulas. In the same way, the book uses $\Rightarrow$ in the meta-language, to abbreviate "if..., then...".

Thus

> $F≡ \top \Rightarrow G≡ \top$

is simply "if $F$ is a tautology, then $G$ is a tautology."

Also the symbol $\vDash$ is **not** part of the language of propositional calculus but is the meta-language symbol for [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence).

Thus

> $F \vDash G$

reads : "there is no [valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic)) $v$ such that $v(F)= \text T$ and $v(G)= \text F$," or (more plainly) :

> "$G$ is TRUE in every interpretation where $F$ is TRUE."

---

The two relations are not the same : we have that "$F \vDash G$" is stronger than "if $F$ is a tautology, then $G$ is a tautology".

Consider the case with $P \lor Q$ as $F$ and $Q$ as $G$; clearly $P \lor Q \nvDash Q$, but $P \lor Q$ is not a tautology, and thus :

> if $P \lor Q$ is a tautology, then $Q$ is a tautology,

holds.

---

---

*Note* : compare with [van Daleen's textbook](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA43), where $\to$ and $\leftrightarrow$ are the conenctives while $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftrightarrow$ are used as abbreviations in the meta-language

Comment: so $\implies$ and $\models$ are both on the same level (statement about formulas), but mean different things? And $\equiv$ and $\to$ are also on the same level, inside a formula?

Comment: Ok i think i understand that now. But one last question: how does $ P \lor Q \equiv \top \implies Q $? Q could be false in the first formula and that would still make the first formula true, but then Q wouldn't be true. Or did i miss something?

Comment: @MarwanEzzat - I've used $P,Q$ as propositional variablles (like $A,B$ in your textbook); thus $P \lor Q$ is **not** a tautology.