# Is the method of direct proof tantamount to showing a formula is a synctactic consequence?

Tags: logic

I have read a number of the great questions and answers regarding syntactic consequence, semantic consequence, the material implication and the logical implication. In particular the answers to this question [$\to$ vs. $\vdash$ in logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903877/to-vs-vdash-in-logic?noredirect=1&lq=1) made it clear that a distinction between the object and metalogical language is important.

My question is about what it means to prove a material conditional statement by direct proof, I.e. to prove $P \rightarrow Q $ by assuming $P$. Is it the case that this method of proof is tantamount to showing the statement (in the meta-language) $P \vdash Q$ is true?

I am quite confused as to whether this is the case or not, as on the one hand from what I've read, it seems like I am confusing the proof in the object language, with a statement in the meta-language.

However at the same time, my understanding of a proof is that we have a sequence of sentences deduced from that are assumptions, axioms, or deduced statements using the rules of inference of our system. To me this means that when we assume $P$ to prove $Q$, we are ultimately trying to show that $P \vdash Q$.

Which of these two notions is correct?

As an additional question, if we have shown that $P \rightarrow Q$ is indeed true, we then eliminate the model of $P$ being true while $Q$ is false as a possibility. Does this mean that $P \vDash Q$ since the only model in which $Q$ is false while $P$ is true is known to be impossible? In other words, if I know in my object language that a particular model is impossible, does this affect the meta-language statement of entailment? (My apologies if this should be posed as a separate question; I thought it was relevant since I think my confusion is stemming in both cases from how the meta-language statements and object language statements affect each other.)

Comment: Basically YES. See [Direct proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_proof) : we assume the premise $P$ and derive $Q$, i.e. we have established the relation : $P \vdash Q$. Then, we apply the [Conditional proof rule (aka: *Conditional introduction*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof) and we conclude with $\vdash P \to Q$.

Comment: And YES: if the proof systems is [*sound*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness#Logical_systems) (i.e. derives only TRUE conclusion from TRUE premises), having established the relation $P \vdash Q$, we can infer that $P \vDash Q$ also holds. And thus : if $\vdash P \to Q$, then $\vDash P \to Q$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you very much, I think i understand the first point. If I could clarify the second point, in general, it would be incorrect to say $p \vDash q$ right? It is only when I have specific information about what $p$ and $q$ are, such that $p \rightarrow q$, that I can say $p \vDash q$? (I suppose in other words I am just checking that in general, the language pertaining to the objects actually influences the metalanguage statements?)

Comment: Nitpicking issue : consider $P,Q$ formulas; otherwise (i.e. if they are propositional letetrs) we cannot have neither $P \vdash Q$ nor $P \vDash Q$.

Comment: Not clear your question... $p \land q \vDash p$ is perfectly correct. Check it with truth table : it is not possible that $p \land q$ is TRUE and $q$ is FALSE.

Comment: A derivation of $p \to q$ in a specified proof system is a finite sequence of formulas such that ... ending with formula $p \to q$. The existence of the derivation is expressed through the metalinguistic statement $\vdash_{PC} p \to q$, where $\text {PC}$ identifies the (propositional) proof system used.

Comment: The Soundness Theorem is a meta-theorem stating that... It is a theorem **about** the proof system and **not** a *derivation* **in** the proof system. Using it, we can infer from $\vdash_{PC} p \to q$ that $\vDash p \to q$.

Comment: The fundamental distinction is that between e.g. $\to$ : a symbol of the language denoting a propositional connective, and $\vdash, \vDash$ that are not part of the language but are used in the meta- to express relations between formuals of the language.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you, I think I understand now!